# How to sort ArrayList of duplicate data using another list in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have two lists listA and listB, listA is a list of unique objects.

```
class item {
    String uniqueID;
    String prop1;
    String prop2
}
```

listB is a list of objects which can have mutiple items with same unique key.

```
listA = { item1 {uniqueID: 1, prop1...}, item2 {uniqueID: 2, prop1....}, item3 {uniqueID: 3, prop...}......}

listB = { item2 {uniqueID: 2, prop1...}, item2{uniqueID: 2, prop1....},item1 {uniqueID: 1, prop...}, item3{uniqueID: 3, prop...}, item3{uniqueID: 3, prop...}...}
```

I want to sort listB in the same order items present in listA, for example listB should look like below example after sort (Note uniqueID of sorted list ) .

```
listB = { item1 {uniqueID: 1, prop...} , item2 {uniqueID: 2, prop1...}, item2 {uniqueID: 2, prop1....}, item3 {uniqueID: 3, prop...}, item3 {uniqueID: 3, prop...}......}}
```

listA will be of fixed size and listB can be >= size of listA. We can say its ordering rather than sorting. I want items of listB to be in order same as listA

How to achieve this in java?

Comment: And what did you try so far ?

Comment: Currently I am creating new list and inserting items by searching items from first list, but it seems like a lot of work, I am looking for something like collections.sort kind of logic

Comment: Code a java.util.Comparator to decide the order of the objects, and pass that to the java.util.ArrayList.sort method.

Comment: @jalynn2, I have around 40 thousands items in listA and want to order another 40 thousands + items as per items in listA. 
In another words I don't have sorting problem rather ordering problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to sort your listB with the uniqueID as sort criteria you can use the java Comparator:

```
    List<Item> listB = Arrays.asList(
    new Item("1", "p1", "p2"),
    new Item("3", "p1", "p2"),
    new Item("3", "p1", "p2"),
    new Item("2", "p1", "p2"),
    new Item("3", "p1", "p2"));

    listB.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getUniqueID));
```

If you want to sort the uniqueIDs of listB in order of listA-uniqueIDs you could use your own Comparator which uses a List of uniqueIds from listA:

```
public class ItemComparator implements Comparator {

private final List<String> aKeys;

public ItemComparator() {
    aKeys = new ArrayList();
}

public ItemComparator(List<String> aKeys) {
    this.aKeys=aKeys;
}

@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
       return aKeys.indexOf(((Item)o1).getUniqueID())-aKeys.indexOf(((Item)o2).getUniqueID());
}
```

}

After that you create a List of your listA-uniqueIDs and pass it to your comparator to sort listB:

```
  List<Item> listA = Arrays.asList(
            new Item("2", "p1", "p2"),
            new Item("1", "p1", "p2"),
            new Item("4", "p1", "p2"),
            new Item("3", "p1", "p2"));

  List<String> keyListA = new ArrayList<>();
  listA.forEach((k)->keyListA.add(k.getUniqueID()));        
  Collections.sort(listB, new ItemComparator(keyListA));
```

Comment: I want listB in order of list A, you are not referring to listA anywhere. uniqeId can be in any order say 5,4,9,2,1,0,10, so listB should have same order as listA.